# Haskell: How do you structure a forking server which you can shutdown properly

Tags: multithreading, haskell

I'm using `network-simple` in my project. I would like my function, `gateway`, to return a few functions in a tuple -- one of which will be `shutdown` -- a function to boot all the clients and shutdown the server.

If `gateway` produces many forks using `Network.Simple.serve`, what's the best way to implement `shutdown`?

I could implement it using `TVar` to indicate the server is shutting down, but polling would be a suboptimal solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways. Somehow you need a control channel to the server, and that control channel accepts at least one message, "Shutdown".

You could do this with:

- asynchronous exception: send the Shutdown data type to the server, which will have a handler to do the client
- test in the event loop: if your server has an eventloop, just treat the incoming control message as part of the event stream
- polling

Comment: I'll just bite the bullet and do some plumbing for bidirectional communication, I guess. Thanks.